# How to get the Eventbrite user's data using eventbrite class

Tags: user-data, eventbrite

How to get the Eventbrite user's  data using eventbrite class.

Regards,
Mistry Sandip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what language you are using, and what type of data that you want to access.
Eventbrite's various API Client libraries are available on their [Open Source Projects](http://eventbrite.github.com/#libraries) page.

Each of Eventbrite's [API request methods](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods) are available as function calls attached to any [initialized](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication) API client object.

See the README file bundled with any of the API Client libraries for more specific information.

Comment: This is the download link for the code,

https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php

u can use this code to retrieve user data.

Regards,
Mistry Sandip